# How to install self-written library on SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

How can I install self-written library functions_lib.py into sql server.

The script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL LIBRARY functions_lib 
FROM (CONTENT = 'my_destination_folder\functions_lib.py')
WITH (LANGUAGE = 'Python');
GO
```

leads to error: Incorrect syntax near 'Python'

I also tried to use the script according to the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806673/where-shall-i-put-my-self-written-python-packages):

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='mypackage')
```

but it leads to error:

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py --help-commands
   or: ipykernel_launcher.py cmd --help

error: option -f not recognized
```

More details:
I have functions_lib.py self-written library which is placed into my working Jupiter Notebook folder. 
I import this library running in Jupiter Notebook:

```
import functions_lib as fl
```

Now I want to install this library on SQL Server.
Usually I install the other external libraries by running the script from the command line:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Scripts
pip.exe install destination_folder\xgboost-0.90-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Or by simple placing unpacked library folder into:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\
```

That worked well.

Comment: You need SQL Server 2019 for Python language support, ref: [CREATE EXTERNAL LIBRARY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-library-transact-sql)

Comment: jarlh, thank you. Is there another method for SQL Server 2017?