# Python: Installing PIP via NTLM from embedded ZIP file

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, pip, ntlm

So I have downloaded the "Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file" from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4-embed-amd64.zip and it works well

I want to install PIP so I also got https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

However it's throwing up a 407 proxy authentication error and despite me putting proxy information in, I presume at this point that NTLM is to blame.

My question is how would I get around this? Is it possible to install PIP/Setuptools via the embeddable zip method 100% offline?

I want to eventually use pandas and requests

I tried what [pip with embedded python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666121/pip-with-embedded-python/48906746#48906746) suggests but get the below:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Using the embeddable zip file but wanting `pip` seems wrong. Could you add what kind of application you are trying to develop that needs both an embedded python and third-party packages?

Comment: I need to use requests and pandas. My problem is I can't install the executable.

Comment: So you just want to write some python code/write a python module?

Comment: Yes - I want to write a script that makes use of requests, pandas and other libraries

Comment: Then you should use a full `python` installation, the embeddable version is not well suited for that task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be complicated but probably not impossible. Also I haven't tested any of this personally, these are more directions that you could look into.

First I would have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906746/11138259). The important point is to find your `python??._pth` file and uncomment the `import site` line.

But you say `get-pip.py` did not work, right? ([from here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#get-pip-py-options))

> `python get-pip.py --proxy="http://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port"`

So you could download the *wheels* another way and then try something like this to bypass the network issues
([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524140/11138259)):

> `python pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install --no-index pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Once you have pip running you can slowly build a Python environment that is comfortable enough to work with. But I believe you would still be severely limited, I think parts of the standard library will be missing and so on.

Maybe you should work on solving the issues preventing you from getting a standard Python installation instead.

Comment: Thanks - will give this a go - IT will not allow us to have it installed because apparently developers aren't to be trusted

Comment: So I gave this a go and still get the same 407 proxy error (as shown in edited question). Proxy is NTLM so don't believe this will work will it?

Comment: Show the command that lead to this error, otherwise it is useless information. My instructions should not need a direct network connection, so I doubt the error you are showing in your edit is relevant.