# Install PyQt for Python3.9 on a computer without internet connection

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install PyQt on a windows computer without internet connection. The computer seems to have a very recent version of Python (Python 3.9.2) so the older.exe files available online don't seem to be compatible.

I downloaded the whl file (PyQt5-5.15.4-cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win32.whl) but I'm not entirely sure where to put it despites trying to print(sys.path) as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132350/install-python-wheel-file-without-using-pip).

Update:
I managed to unzip the whl file and tried placing it in several locations, amongst them the site-packages folder but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: On Windows with internet install python 3.9.2, isntall PyQt2 or better PySide2 and then copy the python to the offline pc and replace files there. That should work? - the most "basic-simple" form of installation I can think of..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@Dariusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873108/dariusz)'s comment I downloaded PyQt5 on a friends computer using the `cmd` command

```
pip install pyqt5
```

and then checked which files were recently installed by checking the Date Modified and then copied those files as a .zip into the site-packages directory on the offline computer and unzipped it there.

Got it working by doing that.