# Python Module Missing Exception in Docker Container, But Clearly Exists

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Docker container that when run, starts a single Python script. On my local machine, the Python script executes without issue. However, the script is unable to find the relevant library files (no external libraries, part of my own repo) that I've confirmed do exist within the container.

Error:
[image]

Directory Structure **Inside** Container:

[image]

Dockerfile:
[image]

Import Statements:
[image]

The repository does contain multiple Dockerfiles in different directories for easier deployment, but removing them did not change this behavior.

Comment: Hi, I think is better if you use virtualenv , this link maybe could help to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31109269/3407798

Comment: @wu4m4n I think the issue with that is that I would have to install pip and all it's dependencies and I'm trying create a very lean package.

Comment: please give us code as text in code blocks, images of text are not as useful.

Comment: I'm guessing however you are running it doesn't put the `tmp` folder on `sys.path` so you can't import it, is the main file you are running inside the package?

Comment: Of the images, two lines are code, the rest is a directory structure, configuration file and and a crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `sys.path.append("/tmp/")` fixed the issue (the directory containing the upper most directory referenced in the import statements).