# Installing Requests module for Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, linux

I have Python Script where "requests" module has been imported.
I am trying to execute this script in Linux terminal and getting error like

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test3.py", line 5, in <module>
        import requests
    ImportError: No module named requests
```

Then, I tried to install the "requests" module by running the below command on Linux terminal and getting some information as below

```
pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So, Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: it sounds silly, but try uninstalling it and reinstalling it

Comment: Hi wpercy, Thanks for the reply. But, I don't have permission to uninstall anything.. This is related to Production host..

Comment: So you can install things but can't uninstall? Why not?

Comment: the error is stating no module named requests. Make sure you know the correct name of the module. Case matters. [where-should-i-put-my-own-python-module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196268/where-should-i-put-my-own-python-module-so-that-it-can-be-imported)

Comment: Maybe you have several versions of python installed. Try to check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory