# Always import same list at beginning of python script

Tags: python, import

I have several python scripts that all start with the same set of lines, and I would like to be able to change the lines only once.

For example something like this:

```
import pickle
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/user/folder/")
import someOtherModules
x=someOtherModules.function()
```

I know I could save this as a string, and then load the string and run the exec() command, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

In other words, I want to import a list of modules and run some functions at the beginning of every script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move all stuff in separate script and in another scripts import everything from it: `from my_fancy_script import *`. In this case not only code inside `my_fancy_script` will be executed but also imports will be pushed to another files.

Anyway, better to use [Delgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119377/6689249)

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own module.

```
# my_init.py
def init():
    print("Initializing...")
```

And simply add this at the beginning of all your scripts:

```
import my_init
my_init.init()
```

Depending on where your scripts and `my_init.py` are located, you may need to add it to your Python user site directory, see: [Where should I put my own python module so that it can be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196400/2291710)

Comment: If I import modules in the init() function will they also be imported in script after if run my_init.init()?  I am trying an example, and not getting it to work.

Comment: in test1.py I have a function def t():import pickle and then in test2.py I import  test1 and then run test1.t() but pickle isn't imported into test2.

Comment: @user1763510 No, it will not work. I read your question too quickly, sorry. An alternative would be as proposed by Aiven to do `import a; import b;` in `my_init.py` and then `from my_init import *` in your scripts. But it's not very elegant, the best is to directly import modules into your scripts.

Comment: Ok, was just wondering if there was a more elegant/pythonic way to do it.