# How to import files from another directory without violation of PEP-8?

Tags: python, python-import, pep8

I have to import file "BalancedTree" from DictsOrganizations to current file. (Organization of files in picture) If I use sys.path.append, I break PEP-8 rules, because there are another imported modules after this code. I also add into DictsOrganizations **init**.py, but there is error "Unable to import "DictsOrganizations"

[image]

Comment: You are also [breaking PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) by giving your packages and modules names ike `BalancedTree` and `DictsOrganizations` :\  Anyway, you can set up the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practises for imports in Python 3 packages and scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185897/best-practises-for-imports-in-python-3-packages-and-scripts)