# How can the changes made in a forked Git repository be implemented in my program without sending a pull request?

Tags: github

I forked a Github repository CANard which is written in python. I added a few more functions to the base program. How can these functions be used in my program? For example, the function dev.recv() in CANard receive only lists in the original base program I included a function which would accept even files and strings how can these functions be implemented in my program without sending a pull request asking the author to add the additional functions to the original program.I want the changes to be made local not permanently to the original repository

Comment: Have you created a local clone of the forked repo - https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo#step-2-create-a-local-clone-of-your-fork ?

Comment: yes I have created a local clone

Comment: Next step is to create a branch from that local clone of the forked repo - https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo#next-steps

Comment: After creating a branch from the local clone of the forked repo will I be able to witness the changes made if I give  dev.recv() in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> After creating a branch from the local clone of the forked repo, will I be able to witness the changes made if I give `dev.recv()` in terminal?

Yes, as long as you are using your local version of the [`gorogit/CANard`](https://github.com/gorogit/CANard), that is the cloned repo of your fork, where you have added your function.

You can then follow "[Where should I put my own python module so that it can be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16196268/6309)"